# What is the difference between proc_terminate and proc_close?

Tags: php

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between [proc_terminate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php) and [proc_close](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php).

**According to docs**:

`proc_terminate`: **Kills** a process opened by `proc_open`

`proc_close`: **Close** a process opened by `proc_open`

What is the difference between killing and closing? and which circumstances I should use one over the other?

Comment: it does say in the docs. terminate *returns immediately and does not wait for the process to terminate*. whilst the other one waits if pipes are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `proc_close` kindly asks a process to close itself (like pressing the close-button in title-bar), whereas `proc_terminate` tells the operating system to stop a process without much waiting (which may cause loss of data).

Comment: Okay, then which signal `proc_close` sends to the system?

Comment: I have not tested yet but it could be `SIGINT` (or `SIGQUIT`, see other possible [signal values](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html))